# Primefaces DataTable p:rowEditor how to retrieve editing status?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

PF 3.5.10, Mojarra 2.1.21, JBoss 7.1.1, PE 7.1, Omnifaces 1.5

I want to use datatable row editing in a p:Dialog.
I have a datatable with a row editing in a Dialog. (Showcase: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowEditing.jsf)
If I click "OK" on the Dialog the changes should be saved, and if I click "Cancel" the changes will be dismissed. If row editing for a row is activated and I can change the values in a row, and then I click "Ok" on a Dialog, the active changes in a row will be lost.
How can I retrieve an actual status of editing ? How can I know if a row in a datatable is currently edited ? If i know that I can warn User that the changes will be lost.

Edit: link to PF sources [Grepcode: PF sources isEditingRow()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.primefaces.org/org.primefaces/primefaces/4.0-20130705.184420-2/org/primefaces/component/datatable/DataTable.java?av=f)

```
<p:dialog>
  <h:form>
     <p:tabView cache="false" id=.. binding=..>
         <p:tab>
            <p:dataTable binding=.. id=... widgetVar=... var=.. >
            </p:dataTable>
         </p:tab>
     </p:tabView>
         <p:commandButton process="@form" action="myBean.listener()" value="OK" update="@form"
           onstart="anotherTable.filter()" />

  </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Edit: I accepted the answer because I implemented the required feature myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you bind the component to your backing bean, or write your own buttons that trigger editing mode which will also set a flag in the backing bean that you can use to determine the status of editing.

Binding the component is probably the easier option...

Comment: What do you mean with "a binding the component" ? I've tried to bind "DataTable" and "RowEditor" Components. The DataTable has isEditingRow()-Method, this method always return false. And I have not found any interesting methods in RowEditor Component. Are there any methods I missed ?

Comment: You may have a phase related problem here. When you click "OK" it processes the form - and probably the edited row. By the time you call isEditingRow() the edit has been completed and the component has already been reset. Are you doing a partialSubmit on the button?

Comment: I updated my answer. I'm using default partial submit value on commandButton, which is false. If I search in PF Sources for isEditingRow() it will be used only once in DataTableRenderer class. I am not sure what for the method is.

Comment: The command button has `process="@form"` which means that the partial submit will process everything in your form. What you need is `process="@this"` (probably for the update too) which will not muck around with the row editor. Now see if in `myBean.listener()` you get a different result for `.isEditingRow()`

Comment: I've tried your advice to replace process="@form" to process="@this" unfortunately it doesn't help.